# Are these questions incorrectly tagged 'codeblocks'?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

I've been searching for some specific Code::Blocks related issues and there are a lot of questions tagged [codeblocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codeblocks) that have nothing to do with the IDE.

Since the tag's mouseover message and [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/codeblocks/info) description are both exclusively about the IDE, I believe all these questions about 'code blocks' are incorrecly tagged; and maybe they need specific tags of their own.

Here are some examples, found from the top 15 questions when searching for questions with the tag (I've already submitted edits for these):

- [Code blocks as 'blocks of code'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463612/passing-multiple-codeblocks-as-arguments)
- [Blocks v. delegates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584404/do-code-blocks-completely-replace-delegates)
- [HTML encoding blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790045/html-encoding-blocks-invalid-expression-term)

Maybe it'd be better to change the tag to something more explicit like 'codeblocks_ide', but I don't know if I have enough standing/reputation to suggest something like that.

Comment: Agree, *usually* the question has nothing to do with the used IDE. The tag does not need changing IMO, *its description should be read* by the people applying it. No way to force that, though--all we can do is remove it when not appropriate.